# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: angular, angular7

Tengo este problema eh visto muchos programas repetidos con lo mismo pero no veo una solución para mi caso podrían ayudarme este es mi código en Angular 7 espero puedan ayudarme

```
    transform(data: any,
            manufFind: string,
            modelFind: string,
  ): any {


    console.log('filter');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(manufFind);
    console.log(modelFind);
    console.log('*********');


    let resultArray = [];
    if (data.length === 0 || manufFind === '') {
      //only filters manufacturer
      return data;
    } else {
      if (modelFind!==''){
        //has model filter
        return data.filter(dfilter =>{
          return dfilter.manufacturerID.toLowerCase().includes(manufFind.toLowerCase()) &&
            dfilter.model.toLowerCase().includes(modelFind.toLowerCase())
        });
      } else{
        return data.filter(dfilter => {
          return dfilter.manufacturerID.toLowerCase().includes(manufFind.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
    }


  }
```

El error que me sale es:

```
ListComponent.html:35 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
at filter-instruments-table.pipe.ts:34
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at FilterInstrumentsTablePipe.push../src/app/modules/list/filter-instruments-table.pipe.ts.FilterInstrumentsTablePipe.transform (filter-instruments-table.pipe.ts:33)
at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:21367)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21933)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListComponent.html:57)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
```

Comment: Hola, antes de cada sentencia `return` asegúrate que tus variables contienen datos. El error es claro, aunque no indicas en qué linea te lo arroja. Un simple `console.log(typeof *variable*)` te puede dar una idea de cuál variable es `null`. Por ejemplo, úsalo con `manufFind`. Saludos

Comment: Bueno mira añadire el codigo completo dejame editar creo que no se copio correctamente

Comment: Estas tratando de convertir a minúsculas una variable que al parecer es de tipo entero. Hazle caso a Mauricio y verifica el tipo de dato

Comment: Trato de buscar un metodo para poderlo convertir ustedes saben si hay algun metodo para poder cambiar un valor entero a minusculas?

Comment: A ver, que eso de enteros en mayúsculas y minúsculas no me lo enseñaron en la escuela. ¿A qué te refieres con ***cambiar un valor entero a minúsculas***?

Comment: Bueno veras cuando elimino mi db completa para agregar nuevas cosas si deja filtrar datos correctamente pero cuando importo nuevos datos no se si ellos afecten el filtrado o quizas por que contenga mayusculas ??

Comment: Mira, en esta línea : `if (data.length === 0 || manufFind === '')` realizas una comprobación sobre `data.length` y seguramente crees que también la realizas sobre `manufFind`. Lo cierto es que el operador `||` es un operador de corto-circuito. Si la primera evaluación (en este caso `data.length === 0`) devuelve `true`, la segunda evaluación no se realiza. Por lo tanto, puedes tener un valor `null` en tu variable `manufFind` y no te has dado cuenta. Revisa eso. Hazle el `console.log(typeof manufFind)` antes de intentar usarla, para que sepas si realmente tiene algo o es `null`.

Comment: Chicos el problema ya lo pudimos resolver al parecer quien afectaba es la base de datos por algunos valores insertados por esa razon el front buscaba pero no encontraba el filtrado correcto gracias por su ayuda